# Android recyclerview expand upwards

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

When using an android recyclerview, the default implementation when expanding items is to push the second half of the recyclerview below the expanding item down. What is the standard way of making it so that the first half of the recyclerview before the expanding item to go up instead? Sort of like the Facebook app.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you have to first fill down side of screen, Please give more details about your problem